# Is it possible to modify the default animation of a FlatList with scrollToOffset in react-native?

Tags: react-native, animation, flatlist

I would like to know if there is a way to manage the **animation duration** and the **easing**, when using **scrollToOffset with Flatlist** ? Even if the solution is with native modifications, I need this :)

Thank you !